# Little triangle in google results

Tags: jquery

Sorry If this has been asked before, but when you search for something on google, you can iterate over the results using the up and down key:

[image]

The little blue triangle, is this done in jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not neccersarly you can you the :focus css selecter to add list-style with desired attribute

example:

```
a:focus {list-style-type:circle;}
```

would give a circle to all focused links
the jquery versioned would be something like

```
$('a').focus(function(){
 $(this).css('list-style','circle');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

They do it with plain JavaScript (not using the jQuery library), but it certainly could be done with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Inspecting the code yields:

```
<span id="knavm" title="Use the up and down arrow keys to select each result. Press Enter to go to the selection." style="padding-top: 0px;">►</span>
```

It's hard to tell how the manipulation is actually done due to their page being compressed, I'm fairly confident it's not jQuery. I'm sure that Google uses their own proprietary system for Javascript.

Replicating something like that would be fairly easy to do using:
http://api.jquery.com/category/events/keyboard-events/